# .Net Unit test compile error - The type or method has 2 generic parameter(s), but 1 generic argument(s) were provided

Tags: .net, unit-testing

We've got a generic class which contains a private class which uses the outer class's generic type parameter.  Example:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  private class Bar : IGrouping<Guid,T>{


  }
}
```

The problem is that we get a compile error in a unit test project which states

> "The Type or method has 2 generic parameter(s), but 1 generic argument(s) were provided.  A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter."

I cranked up MSBuild verbosity (Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run).  Looking at the error location, it points to the Microsoft.TeamTest.targets file.  I was able to narrow it down to this class structure above.  If I replace the private class Bar with concrete generic parameters in the class definition (see below), the unit test compiles fine:

```
private class Bar : IGrouping<Guid,int>{

}
```

I need to provide that second generic parameter *generic* to accept whatever the type is in the outter class.  Thoughts on this one?

To clarify, the compile error is in the Unit Test Project, *not* the code listed above (which compiles fine).  Perhaps the private accessor generation is choking in the MS unit test infrastructure?

Here's [almost] the entire actual code:

```
public class CategoryStorageService<T> : StorageServiceBase<T>, ICategoryStorageService<T> where T : IStorageContent, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a nested object graph of category-items
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="categories"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<StorageCategory, T>> GetContent(params StorageCategory[] categories)
    {
        var results = this.GetContent(categories.Select(c => c.ID).ToArray());
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            yield return new LocalNameGrouping(
                categories.First(c => c.ID == result.Key.ID),
                result);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a nested object graph of categories, each containing their items
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="categories">The ID(s) of the category(ies) to fetch</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerable<IGrouping<StorageCategory, T>> GetContent(params Guid[] categories)
    {

        // implementation removed

        return null;
    }      

    private class LocalNameGrouping : IGrouping<StorageCategory, T>
    {
        private IEnumerable<T> items;
        private StorageCategory category;

        public LocalNameGrouping(StorageCategory localCategory, IGrouping<StorageCategory, T> items)
        {
            this.items = items;
            string name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(localCategory.DisplayName) ? items.Key.DisplayName : localCategory.DisplayName;
            this.category = new StorageCategory { DisplayName = name, ID = items.Key.ID };
        }

        #region IGrouping<StorageCategory,T> Members

        public StorageCategory Key
        {
            get { return category; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<T> Members

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `IGrouping`

Comment: Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: @AakashM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the unit test code might be useful to point the problem here... can you give it to us too ?

Comment: The unit test code is not failing at a specific point, in fact, this class is not even tested in the unit test project.  The compile of the unit test project is failing.  If I provide a concrete type for that second generic parameter, then voila.

Comment: Are you sure CategoryStorageService or LocalNameGrouping are not referenced somewhere in your test project ?

Answer (score 2):

So the private accessor processing was angry at a type that had partially constructed generic class definitions.  For example, it failed if the class was declared like this:

```
private class LocalNameGrouping : IGrouping<StorageCategory, T> { 

}
```

However, it was happy with this, which still satisfied the need (albeit a tad cheesy):

```
private class LocalNameGrouping<K> : IGrouping<K, T> where K: StorageCategory, new()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't been able to repro the problem.  I filled out your sample with the code below and it compiles just fine in Visual Studio 2010.

```
public class StorageServiceBase<T> { }
public interface ICategoryStorageService<T> { }
public interface IStorageContent { }
public class StorageCategory { }
public interface IGrouping<T1, T2> : IEnumerable<T2> { }

public class CategoryStorageService<T> : StorageServiceBase<T>, ICategoryStorageService<T> where T : IStorageContent, new() {
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<StorageCategory, T>> GetContent(params StorageCategory[] categories) {
        return null;
    }
    private IEnumerable<IGrouping<StorageCategory, T>> GetContent(params Guid[] categories) {
        return null;
    }

    private class LocalNameGrouping : IGrouping<StorageCategory, T> {
        private IEnumerable<T> items = null;
        private StorageCategory category = null;

        public LocalNameGrouping(StorageCategory localCategory, IGrouping<StorageCategory, T> items) {
        }

        #region IGrouping<StorageCategory,T> Members

        public StorageCategory Key {
            get { return category; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<T> Members

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
            return items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: but if you create a private accessor for that assembly, does the unit test project also compile? That is the issue.

Comment: @Rex, then I would say it's almost certainly a bug in private accessors.  Is this VS 2005 or VS 2008+ (very different implementations)

Comment: @Rex, sounds very much like a bug.  Could you file it on connect? http://connect.microsoft.com/